# How to check Internet Speed via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, internet, download-speed

Instead of going to sites like [speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net/), I want to check my current Internet speed from the terminal on Ubuntu. How can I do it?

Comment: The results I'm getting with speedtest-cli are vastly under what I get from speedtest.net speedtest-cli Download 18.27 Mbits/s Upload 3.43 Mbits/s speedtest.net Download 59.38 Mbits/s Upload 12.14 Mbits/s I can't consider speedtest-cli to be in any way a valid test of network speed.

Comment: @user375058: The `speedtest-cli` uses the same servers (etc.) as SpeedTest.net. You should consider the `speedtest-cli` and `www.speedtest.net` to be equivalent, just with a different front-end. I would be surprised if you get *significantly* different results consistently if they both use the same server. If they aren't using the same server, then you have no basis for comparison. Lastly, my results for both utilities vary by a factor of 2-4 from run to run. I suggest you test 2-4 servers, and perform 3–4 runs for each server and compare tools.

Comment: @user375058: I actually just did what I suggested. See the link in my comment below for my results.

Comment: sudo apt install speedtest-cli

Answer (score 1179, accepted):

I recommend the [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) tool for this. I created a blog post ([Measure Internet Connection Speed from the Linux Command Line](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2013/03/measure-internet-connection-speed-from-linux-command-line.html)) that goes into detail of downloading, installing and usage of it.

The short version is this: *(no root required)*

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
```

Output:

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Testing from Comcast Cable (x.x.x.x)...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by FiberCloud, Inc (Seattle, WA) [12.03 km]: 44.028 ms
Testing download speed........................................
Download: 32.29 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed..................................................
Upload: 5.18 Mbit/s
```

### Update in 2016:

`speedtest-cli` is in Ubuntu repositories now. For Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and later use:

```
sudo apt install speedtest-cli
speedtest-cli
```

### Update in 2018:

Using `pip install --user speedtest-cli` gets you a version that is probably newer than the one available from your distribution's repositories.

```
speedtest-cli
```

### Update in 2022:

```
sudo apt install speedtest-cli
speedtest-cli --secure
```

Comment: Can you summarize the important information from your blog post in your answer?

Comment: The blog post is just an explanation about the program and how to install it. The program is a tool for measuring speed just like speedtest.net does, using the same servers (and automatically location the nearest).

Comment: This doesnt seem to work properly. I have BT infinity 50bBit down and 20Mbit up. But the results show up as 0.53Mbit down and 0.2Mbit up. Huh? Incorrect decimal placing? using wget I get 4.27M/s (34Mbit) (some other server though)?

Comment: Installing git might be overkill for most Ask Ubuntu readers. You can just download the repo from https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/archive/master.zip

Comment: As it has already been stated [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/385015/112263):
Since speedtest-cli is a python application, it is much easier to install by doing:

    `pip install speedtest-cli`

or:

    `easy_install speedtest-cli`

Depending on how Python is installed on your system, you may need to be root to do the above.

Comment: Here is a simple bash script I wrote for handy tool, using `notify-send` and `zenity` to display the output graphically instead of terminal: http://ubuntuone.com/49YdNJBRtYIdaS1eY8jrpw

Comment: Confirming that **speedtest-cli is broken**. Doesn't show speeds above 1Mbps. Doesn't transfer any info when claiming to do so.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer...speedtest-cli is working fine for me; think @int_ua was either having compatibility problems or internet problems.

Comment: After using `pip install speedtest-cli` to install the script and then running it with `speedtest-cli` the scrit seems to freeze up while at the line `Testing download speed................` **How long should this test take?** It has been over 40 min now, while I was waiting I used speedtest.net and measured ping at 75ms, download speed at 6.36Mbps, and upload speed at 0.98Mbps. I am using Ubuntu 14.10 with python 2.7.8

Comment: This should be the right answer. Speed test means download AND upload. First answer ONLY measures the download speed, which is NOT a full picture of your internet connection speed. Especially if you are hosting something on that machine!

Comment: how can we select a server? I know of servers that can go beyond gigabit speeds.

Comment: Very nice blog post about command line usage for speetest-cli. Thanks!

Comment: thank you for the elegant code and support for python 3 and 2. !

Comment: @JemiloII: To get a list of all SpeetTest.net servers, type `./speedtest-cli --list` (use `grep` to find the server you're thinking of). It returns servers in the format `XXXX) Company Name (Location, State/Province/Country) [DDD.DD km]`, where XXXX is the server ID (numeric) and DDD.DD is the estimated distance in kilometers from your machine. Then, to perform the test with a given server, type `./speedtest-cli --server XXXX`, using the same numeric server ID you found in the previous step.

Comment: @Willoczy: it takes 5-25 seconds for me. In the SpeedTest.net web page, it sometimes complains that there's a missing Latency File. I don't know what's going on, but that message seems to exist for certain servers. I'd choose a different server manually. Perhaps the one you were using was having issues?

Comment: @int_ua: I can partially confirm that it is broken. I ran 3 tests via Speedtest.net and the `speedtest-cli` tool for 8 servers across North America. My results are tabulated [here](http://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~vriesema/files/speedtest_results.txt). There is a significant, systematic difference between the two approaches. That said, in about half the cases, it's not off by a very significant amount...but half the time it is. The biggest finding was that the upload speeds were consistently lower (usually 50-70% the speed) in the `speedtest-cli` run than the browser version. Odd.

Comment: The problem is still there in 2016. I did a few tests and have results similar (in nature) to those of @jvriesem. It is a pity as the tool would be very useful. I am wondering whether it can be used for comparisons (say, a few VPN servers - it would not really matter to know how fast they are but rather to be able to predictably compare them to get the fastest one)

Comment: You can also skip the `chmod` command and just run `python speedtest-cli`.

Comment: sudo apt install speedtest-cli

Comment: Don't work for me. Tested on `Linux Kali 4.3.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-7kali2 (2016-01-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux` with `Python 2.7.13`. With and without root previllages, the resuld is 0.00 D and 0.00 U speed. I even selected server using `speedtest-cli --server XXXX`

Comment: not good for testing high speed connections

Comment: I have a 1000Mbps connection, gives me 7Mbps down 0.2Mbps up, I follow the test with my system updates, it dowloads it at 24Mbps... I tried both the command line and speedtest-cli

Comment: For me the `python script` works better than the `speedtest-cli`. I have tested on the same machine, with `python script` I got 93MB/92MB (almost the same for 3 different tests) and with `speedtest-cli` I got 91MB/32MB.

Comment: 2018 Uprdate: speedtest-cli installed from Ubuntu repositories works as speedtest.net

Comment: 760 Mbit/s down, 698 Mbit/s from the apt-get install method. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Confirming that it's possible to consistently get a 1-4 Mbit/s with `speedtest-cli`, while getting 1500+ Mbit/s using the Python script piped from `curl`. The Python script it pulled directly from the GitHub master branch, so it likely has some bug-fixes that aren't in the ubuntu repos. `speedtest-cli` works fine on one of my machines (it is running Ubuntu 20.04), but not on the other (18.04). I don't know if it has to do with the Ubuntu version. Just be weary if you see very low numbers.

Comment: curl command provided works good for devices where we do not want to install any extra applications, however small they may be.

Comment: If you want to log speed test info with date and time,  I like to do this bash one liner: `while :; do; echo "$(date): $(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python3 - --simple | tr '\n' ' ')"; done 2>&1 | tee ~/speed_test_log.txt`

Comment: Can someone edit and change python to python3?

Answer (score 146):

try this on command line

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

try this too

```
sourceforge.net/projects/tespeed/
```

got it from above link

Comment: Could you plz explain what `/dev/null` stands for?

Comment: It  is speacial file which simply the delete data written to it,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 14.10 with python 2.7.8 the command `wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip` works much better than using `speedtset-cli` the later seems to freeze and ^C fails to interrupte the command. With wget I have no problems cutting the download shrot with ^C

Comment: Definitely not a good test for me. `speedtest-cli` gave a speed of about 12MB/s. This gave about 1.5MB/s.

Comment: @mlissner, looks like first speed in megabits, second in megabytes..

Comment: @mlissner 1.5 x 8 =12 . one is kbps and other is KBps :-)

Comment: Note that the test file is a 500 MB file. You can change the `test500.zip` to `test10.zip` (for example) to try a 10 MB file. I hear this also works with 100 MB.

Comment: Also, note that this only tests download speed, not upload. `speedtest-cli` seems like a better option.

Comment: `./tespeed.py` is working fine, although  i would prefere `speedtest-cli` if it was working properly. But, beware to download files inside "SocksiPy" also. Tespeed is testing connection download and upload speed by using specific file sizes.

Comment: Note that speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com is just one specific Speedtest server. There are thousands of them all over the world, and depending on where you are located, testing with this one may or may not give you correct results. Speedtest.net choses the server closest to you automatically, which should be more relevant. Ideally, you should use your browser's Dev Tools to figure out the hostname/URL speedtest.net choses in your case and use that in the wget line above instead of speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com.

Comment: I had to test the speed of a docker container which did not have wget.
This worked:
curl --output /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip

Comment: On the Ubiquity AP I just had to speed test from, `wget` was not available, but instead, `curl -o /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip` worked - not with an overwhelming performance.

Comment: Is that softlayer server link still up? I can't seem to access it, no response coming back, hangs when try the URL in browser or via wget

Comment: @David I confirm that the reported URL is down also for me.

Comment: I'm updating the question to keep this exact solution but with the URL https://www.ip-toolbox.com/speedtest-files/ that seems more reliable and it's online at the time of writing

Answer (score 83):

If you can't be bothered to install iperf , you could precede any command that shifts a known amount of data with the `time` command and do a sum.

iperf is simple and easy to use.

It requires a client and server.

(on the server)

```
 user@server$ iperf -s
```

(on the client)

```
 user@client$ iperf -c server.domain
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Client connecting to 192.168.1.1, TCP port 5001
 TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 [  3] local 192.168.1.3 port 52143 connected with 192.168.1.1 port 5001
 [ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
 [  3]  0.0-10.0 sec    113 MBytes  94.7 Mbits/sec
```

[More Details](https://superuser.com/questions/70399/linux-command-line-bandwidth-speed-tests/70416#70416)

Comment: +1 iperf is fantastic for validating ethernet and WIFI speeds

Comment: `iperf` is great for LAN but the user is asking about WAN.

Comment: Those of you who don't have a remote server you can connect to, there are publicly available iperf servers: https://iperf.cc/

Comment: speedtest is useless as most internet providers know their servers' addresses and prioritize them. I get results with iperf that are a 10th of what speedtest gives me. And those are the effective speeds I reach.

Comment: @dargaud Make sure you don't mix TCP speed with UDP speed. Most speed test tools measure UDP speed, but iperf measures TCP by default. Use `iperf -u -c servername` to measure UDP speed. The results of that will probably be very close to what speedtest gives you.

Comment: If you want to test the WAN get a public server from the official site: https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php

Answer (score 39):

Well I use `wget` for it. That little tool tells me nicely what speed I have.

To use it just point to a file in internet that is relatively bigger so that you can get a better estimate of it.

For example

typing: `wget http://hostve.com/neobuntu/pics/Ubu1.avi` would start to download the Ubu1.avi file and show at what speed it is downloading.

[image]

Of course there are several recommendations:

1. Speed test yourself with good servers. In the case of my link the speed is less than 200KB so if you have a higher speed, the server will be the bottleneck for you, not your actual speed.
2. The highest speed you will see is the maximum speed that your connection and the server's connection can offer. If your connection is 512KB and the place where you are downloading is 400KB, your max connection will be 400KB because it is the max for the server you are downloading from.
3. You need to do the test at least 5 times to have a reliable speed check or at least do it for a minute or two. This will help you have a more accurate check.
4. You need to have at least 4 or 5 different testing sources to have a more accurate speed. Never test only from the same site as this can be affected by your distance to it, any problem in the server and the connections to it, etc. Always test from different servers.

**ARIA2**

This is an alternative to `wget`. The downside of `wget` is the lack of parallel connections. To use aria2 we fist need to download it:

```
   sudo apt-get install aria2
```

To use it is simple:

[image]

In the image, the **-x 4** is how many parallel connections we wish to use. The CN parameter in the next line shows how many active parallel connections were permitted to download from that site. In this case CN is 4. But if we tried to have more connections we would get something like this:

[image]

We set 8 parallel connections but the site only allowed a maximum of 5 as shown by CN:5. This could be solved by the **-j** option which tells aria2c the maximum concurrent connections we want (Which by default is 5) but if the server has limited this, -j will not work.

Comment: wget is not (yet) able to do a segmented download, that is to download a single file using multiple (parallel) connections, so if your ISP is limiting the speed per 1 connection, you won't get accurate results... it would be a more precise test to use some other tool, that can at least use segmented download (like aria2)

Comment: @MladenB. Thanks. Added Aria2 to it.

Comment: This is NOT a speedtest, this is a DOWNLOAD speed test only! Internet speed test means down&up load! Second answer, and all others mentioning speedtest-cli have the correct approach.

Comment: @EmilBorconi You are correct but in real life, we are not doing benchmarking Internet speeds here, this are just your average current speed tests of any home user without the need for sites like speedtest. A download speed (Which is enough for anyone trying to see if they are having a bottleneck) is a good enough test. A full down/up speed test would check what the full scope of your speed is based on your ISP. So yeah that would be the best solution, but for any fast test scenario, even a simple wget would do the trick since normally people worry more about download speed than upload.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado sorry if I sounded rude, just I think people should be able to fully understand what they are asking / and what is the accepted answer. Lot's of newbies will look at forums and they will assume / pick / stop at the accepted answer, and they form a false image in their had. And yes download is more important then upload unless you are a facebook maniac who post selfies each 5 minutes, then start a fight with you ISP just because you tested the download which is good, but you have a crappy upload... Once again sorry if my tone was rude, did not want to insult...

Comment: @EmilBorconi don't worry friend, we appreciate your feedback and they help anybody that reads this in the future.

Comment: FYI, I had Axel (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/axel) installed already (using it for parallel connections), so it works fine for this purpose.

Comment: I like `wget` better than `curl` for this because `wget` displays `MB/s` (very clear that is MBytes/s), whereas `curl` just displays `k` (not very obvious that it is KBytes/s).

Comment: `aria2c -d /dev -o null --allow-overwrite=true --file-allocation=none -x 4 http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip` https://serverfault.com/a/526305/190486

Answer (score 21):

Since speedtest-cli is a python application, it is much easier to install by doing:

```
pip install speedtest-cli
```

or:

```
easy_install speedtest-cli
```

Depending on how Python is installed on your system, you may need to be root to do the above.

Answer (score 15):

I'm regularly using something like this:

```
% wget -O /dev/null --progress=dot:mega http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test ; date
--2020-01-06 03:31:05--  http://cachefly.cachefly.net/10mb.test
Resolving cachefly.cachefly.net (cachefly.cachefly.net)... 2607:7700::18:0:1:cdea:afaf, 205.234.175.175
Connecting to cachefly.cachefly.net (cachefly.cachefly.net)|2607:7700::18:0:1:cdea:afaf|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 10485760 (10M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: <</dev/null>>

     0K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 30% 3.02M 2s
  3072K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 60% 3.97M 1s
  6144K ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ ........ 90% 3.94M 0s
  9216K ........ ........                                    100% 3.99M=2.8s

2020-01-06 03:31:08 (3.62 MB/s) - <</dev/null>> saved [10485760/10485760]

Mon Jan  6 03:31:08 CST 2020
%
```

You can change the `10mb` part in `/10mb.test` to `1mb`, `4mb`, `5mb`, `10mb`, `50mb`, `100mb`, `200mb`, `400mb`, `2000mb`, `4000mb`, and possibly some other values.

You can also change the `--progress=dot:mega` part to `--progress=dot:default`, `--progress=dot:binary`, `--progress=dot:mega` and `--progress=dot:giga`; this setting helps you see how fast the download is going, and preserve more than a single reading over the whole duration of the download, which is helpful for when you need to share the results with someone, or just save it for your own records as a sort of a graph.

Comment: Can't comment yet; for very limited situations: 
```echo -e "Simple CLI Connection Speed Test\n================================"
echo    "Available file sizes (MB): 1, 4, 5, 10, 50, 100, 200, 400, 2000, 4000";
read -p "Choice: " size;
downloadUrl=http://cachefly.cachefly.net/${size}mb.test
echo -e "\nDonwload url: ${downloadUrl}\n"
startTime=$(date +"%s");
wget  $downloadUrl -O ->/dev/null;
endTime=$(date +"%s");
totalTime=$(expr $(($endTime-$startTime)));
echo -e "\nResults\n=======\nDownloaded in: $totalTime second(s)";
echo "Speed: $(expr 8 \* $size / $totalTime) Mbit/s";```

Answer (score 12):

I happen to like the `speedometer` Ubuntu cli.

```
speedometer -r eth0
```

To watch a live graph of incoming data speeds.

Comment: thats actually what I was looking for for a while! thanks! but I dont like that it shows speeds in Kib and not Kb or KB

Comment: @redbeam_ KiBs are easier to work with, because they're `2**10`, rather than `10**3`.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick that’s subjective and depends on the situation and context.

Answer (score 7):

a simple one-liner that tests how long it takes to download 100MB (works on `/bin/sh` also):

`t=$(date +"%s"); wget http://speedtest.tele2.net/100MB.zip -O ->/dev/null ; echo -n "MBit/s: "; expr 8 \* 100 / $(($(date +"%s")-$t))`

explanation:

1. store the timestamp in $t
2. download 100mb but don't store anything
3. calculate `8 * 100mb / $t`

Comment: This worked great as I'm testing from a stateless read-only rootFS and `wget` wasn't outputting the speed.

Comment: As simple and barebones as it is, this might be the only option when you want to test connection speed but have limited Internet access to only one website.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Ookla, the provider of [Speedtest](http://www.speedtest.net) released a command-line utility that is measuring your speed against a huge number of servers spread around the world. You can find instructions on how to install it on this [link](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) and you can use it fairly simple by executing:

```
speedtest -s XXXX -f csv|tsv|jsonl|json|json-pretty
```

where `-s` sets the server ID against which you want to test your Internet speed, `-f` is defining the format of the output. I think the most useful information is generated when you use `json/json-pretty` format for the output because a lot of the information of the test setup isn't printed if you are using the `csv/tsv` format. Both `-s` and `-f` are just optional but if you want to automate your measurement they might be useful.

In addition, you can find a list of the servers which speedtest is using on this [address](https://c.speedtest.net/speedtest-servers-static.php) in the form of an XML file or on this address with a searchable field: [link](http://www.speedtestserver.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Run several instances of wget with timeout command on large files:

```
#!/bin/bash

timeout 5 wget -q url_1/100MB.zip &
timeout 5 wget -q url_2/file.zip &
timeout 5 wget -q url_3/sample.mov &
timeout 5 wget -q url_4/speech.mp4 &
```

And then write a script to calculate the total bytes downloaded and divide 5 seconds you will get a bytes/sec figure. Should be quite accurate and you can add more instances to max your bandwidth.

I have yet to test the full script but the single line command "timeout 5 wget url" works, and you get a partially downloaded file as a result (if 5 secs is not enough to complete the download).

Comment: This would require of some server set up...

Comment: url_1,2,3,4 can be anything, such as public servers.

Comment: for example `timeout 5 wget http://speedtest.netcologne.de/test_100mb.bin -O /tmp/temp5sec` then analyze the filesize and devide by 5: `expr $(stat --printf="%s" /tmp/temp5sec) / 5 / 1024` in kbit/s

Answer (score 3):

you can use `tespeed` . it is a Terminal network speed test that uses servers from `Speedtest.net`. It uses nearest test server but can also use one manually specified by the user.

```
 git clone git://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed.git
 cd tespeed
 git submodule init
 git submodule update
 ./tespeed.py
```

[image]

for  more info use :

```
 ./tespeed.py  -h
```

it will provide more option for speed test.

Comment: Note: requires `lxml`

Comment: It returns an error: `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1`

Answer (score 2):

Simple bash script based on @rexis answer. You can put your own links for testing in `links` array or read them from file

```
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C  #make output in English eg for later use with "du | grep"

TMP_PATH=/tmp/speedtest_data/
TEST_TIME=5

rm -rf $TMP_PATH && mkdir $TMP_PATH

links=("http://client.cdn.gamigo.com/bp/eu/com/110a/BPClientSetup-2b.bin" "http://client.cdn.gamigo.com/bp/eu/com/110a/BPClientSetup-1b.bin" "http://client.cdn.gamigo.com/bp/eu/com/110a/BPClientSetup-1c.bin" "http://ftp.ntua.gr/pub/linux/ubuntu-releases-dvd/quantal/release/ubuntu-12.10-server-armhf+omap.img" "http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/Linux/INSTALL/Ubuntu/dvd-releases/releases/12.10/release/ubuntu-12.10-server-armhf+omap.img" "http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/Linux/opensuse/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-DVD-x86_64.iso")

echo "Testing download"

for link in ${links[*]}
do
    timeout $TEST_TIME wget -q -P $TMP_PATH $link &
done

wait

total_bytes=$(du -c -b $TMP_PATH | grep total | awk '{print $1}')

echo "Cleaning up"
rm -rf $TMP_PATH

speed=$(echo "scale=2; $total_bytes / $TEST_TIME / 128" |bc)

echo "Speed is $speed Mbit/s"

exit 0
```

Comment: one minus - what about when i use other language as English ?  see: grep :) part

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something more advanced than speedtest.net and various solutions that rely solely on a single website.  So I did the thing I normally do and wrote my own solution:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/network-speedtest-cli

From the features list:

- SSH/SFTP (port 22) speed testing.
- Common TCP ports 80, 443, and 8080 as well as random TCP port speed testing using a custom TCP/IP server that supports speeds up to 2.2 Gbps down and 780 Mbps up.
- Fairly basic network latency testing.
- Spin up Digital Ocean droplets and speed test SSH/SFTP and various TCP ports.
- Speedtest.net and custom OoklaServer speed testing.  Produces similar results to the single connection tests at single.speedtest.net.
- Pure JSON output in silent mode (-s).

It's a more generic solution that can be consumed by other applications.  I managed to pinpoint an ISP network issue with it that resulted in doubling my SFTP downstream speed, which resulted in increased happiness.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try http://dl.getipaddr.net

They use curl (which is a well known command line utility) to run a speed test.

In short

wget https://raw.github.com/blackdotsh/curl-speedtest/master/speedtest.sh && chmod u+x speedtest.sh && bash speedtest.sh

Answer (score 1):

To conveniently get my download speed in bits-per-second, I define the following in my $HOME/.bash_aliases file:

```
speed-test='wget --output-document=/dev/null --report-speed=bits http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip'
```

where:

`--output-document=/dev/null` effectively discards the wget output

`--report-speed=bits` displays the wget download speed average in bits-per-second (bps) instead the default bytes-per-second (Bps)

Answer (score 1):

### For charts + the 30,000 feet view of representative actual speeds

I was looking for:

- A broad, multi-ISP, representative view of real-life speeds
- Upload-speeds + round-trip latencies. Not just download speeds
- Eliminate ISP bias and possible tricks they might play to make specific speed-tests appear faster than most other speeds are
- High-level graphical output rather than just numbers. One picture is worth a 1000 words

Not being able to find anything that answered all these requirements, I wrote my own while avoiding reinventing the wheel wherever possible.

Under the hood, I used `speedtest-cli` for the ISP selection and the metrics, and `R/ggplot` for plotting.  The code has been well tested on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 & 20.04.

The output provides the 3 main metrics (download, upload, and ping round-trip times) for the closest 20 data-centers to you (the tester), plus estimated distances and Internet provider names.

### Source code

[All the code is available from github](https://github.com/arielf/speedtests/) with howto, examples & my story of looking for better speeds.

All this code is CLI based. The image viewer can also be called from the command line.

### Example of the charts it generates

#### After a plan upgrade (DL-speeds are great, UL-speeds not so much)

[image: results 2020-05-25]

#### A manually annotated earlier test, testing a theory:

[image: manually annotated earlier test]