# Download/upload speed indicator applet for 14.04

Tags: internet, 14.04, indicator, applet

I need a net speed indicator applet for Ubuntu 14.04. In Ubuntu 12.04 I installed it as shown in: [How to display network upload / download speed on the panel in Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-display-network-upload-download.html), but this is not working in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is not working?  It is difficult to diagnose issues if you dont specify any error messages etc.  Have a look here if you are having issues installing indicator-sysmonitor - http://askubuntu.com/a/453975/14356

Comment: I recommend (and use) **System Load Indicator**, available in *Software Centre*.

Comment: How can I install it?@ david6

Comment: I had it installed (under **13.10**), and it works well under **14.04 LTS**. *It is in **Software Centre**.*

Comment: @ david6 , This software is working fine. But it is showing net speed through graph. How can I see net speed in digit??

Answer (score 3):

Indicator multiload has that and much more

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

to start it up:

```
indicator-multiload &
```

You can set it to print a graph for each category, you can set it to display text, or you can set it to display both.

Categories include: CPU, memory, netspeed, swap, load, and disk IO speed.

Answer (score 2):

See this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335) to get you started.  Note that `indicator-sysmonitor` was [forked](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor) and now works again in Ubuntu 14.04.

You'll have to modify the custom script to get network speed though, using perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/269821/67335) as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Install Indicator Netspeed in Ubuntu.

Run the following in your terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed
```

i got answer from this [site](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/indicator-netspeed-displays-network.html)

ANOTHER NETWORK SPEED UBUNTU APP INDICATOR.

install Dconf Editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then navigate to apps > indicators > netspeed-unity and change the settings to suit your needs. Note that changing some of the settings that are only available via Dconf Editor requires restarting the indicator to apply them.

Install Indicator Netspeed Unity in Ubuntu.

```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
```

I got this ANOTHER NETWORK SPEED UBUNTU APP INDICATOR form [HERE.](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/yet-another-network-speed-ubuntu.html)

Comment: Not working in 16.04 (or 14.04 as far as I can remember.)

Comment: try with [this.](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/yet-another-network-speed-ubuntu.html)