# Is it possible to check internet speed using the ping command?

Tags: ping

Is it possible to check internet speed using the ping command ?

Ping determines the time to receive a reply, which could be used to calculate the average round trip speed provided we know the internet addresses of some standard servers.

Is t possible to separate the round trip times into the going and returning times so that upload and download speeds could be separated ?

Comment: I don't think so, but not sure. You can specify the size of each ping package though and increase it to a few kB or MB, which is probably more useful than trying to time the normal tiny packages.

Comment: For what you want you could use `speedtest-cli` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/269821/423684) instead or simply use `wget` as mentioned [here too](https://askubuntu.com/a/104769/423684)

Comment: `ping` operates on  the transport/network layers of OSI network model, which means it can test if a host is up or how long it takes to reach the host, but it doesn't take into account what other protocols do. It cannot measure "Internet" speed, and doesn't take into account how long websites may take to process your request. It's a very limited network test, so I don't think it's suitable for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 4):

To my own surprise this acually seems to be possible: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575537/calculate-upload-download-speed-by-ping)

However I would only recommand to use this methode in a LAN network. If you want to check your internet speed use `speedtest` 
You can install it via apt:

```
apt install speedtest-cli
```

Then just run the command

```
speedtest
```

and it will measure you internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

Ping defines as 32/64 bytes data transfers from your side of web connection to remote side of.

Generally, you can think of possiblity of obtaining speed of internet connection

**However**,
When you pinging, another situations may be in active, such as type of internet connection(adsl, fiber optic etc.)

One other thing we cannot eliminate is the connection distance between two remote server, for instance when pinging to google from estonia or india or anywhere else makes different solution due to distance of google server...

and also your internet sharing from other connections make your connection limit upper so transfer and communication gets slower.

finally, your internet speed verification not only element effecting ping speed actually so that you can not get clear conclusion to test your speed.