# How to install netspeed in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I tried installing *netspeed* via terminal but no luck, also tried to find out it on Ubuntu software app but there also no such app available, it seems like there is no *netspeed* for Ubuntu 20.04, please help me.

Comment: The `netspeed` package seems to have been dropped from Ubuntu sometime after 16.04...four years ago. Perhaps a newer alternative might be acceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check Internet Speed via Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help, I referred this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is here ...

https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed

clone project by

> git clone https://github.com/hedayaty/NetSpeed
>
> cd NetSpeed
>
> make install
>
> make enable

Output is zip file, extract to your local config path.

Restart ubuntu, open "tweaks" to customize.

Comment: where is local config path in ubuntu?

Comment: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/download-upload-speed-ubuntu-20-04-panel/