# speedtest cli ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency

Tags: command-line, 20.04, internet, python3, download-speed

I used successfully the simple script

```
$ cat com/speedtestcli
#!/bin/bash

#
# check internet speed
#
#https://askubuntu.com/questions/104755/how-to-check-internet-speed-via-terminal
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python3
```

An I also tried the package version

```
speedtest-cli --secure
```

In both case the scripts fail with this terminal output:

```
$ com/speedtestcli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from YYYYYYY (x.x.x.x)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.
```

Or

```
$ speedtest-cli --secure
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from YYYYYYY (x.x.x.x)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
ERROR: Unable to connect to servers to test latency.
```

Considering i'm using Ububtu 20.04 and python 3.8.10.
There is known reason speedtest fails?
There is any alternitive program I can run from command line?

Comment: You can download the official Speedtest cli program from Ookla https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli . They have .deb as well as .tgz files.

Answer (score 0):

The snap `fast` will run from the command line.

`snap install fast`

Then invoke it from the command line with `fast`

Alternatively, install it from Ubuntu Software.

[image]

Comment: I got 
`$ fast
 -> 0 Kbps`

Comment: reset your router?